# How are \DeclareMathOperator and \operatorname different from the \def family and \pgfmathsetmacro?

Tags: macros, math-operators, function, define

LaTeX has so many similar yet different ways of creating new macros/commands/functions and it is quite confusing. How do `\DeclareMathOperator` and `\operatorname` differ from other common definition commands?

Answer (score 4):

`\operatorname`is not a definition at all, `\operatorname{log}` is essentially `\mathop{\mathrm{log}}`  (with some details omitted)

`\DeclareMathOperator\mylog{log}` is essentially `\def\mylog{\operatorname{log}}`

Providing a LaTeX name provides a more consistent syntax, ensures the details are *not* omitted (eg `\operatorname{S}` sits on the baseline, but `\mathop{\mathrm{S}}` would be like `\sum` and vertically centred)  It can also make use of LaTeX syntax for related definitions such as star form `\DeclareMathOperator*` (to control `\limits` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* other methods for assigning a meaning to a control sequence, but `\operatorname` isn't among them.

- `\def \gdef \edef \xdef` and `\let` (but use them with care)
- `\newcommand \renewcommand \providecommand`
- `\DeclareRobustCommand`
- `\NewCommandCopy \RenewCommandCopy`
- `\newlength \newsavebox` (and other `\new...`)
- `\DeclareMathSymbol` and friends (look into `fontmath.ltx`)
- `\DeclareTextCommand` and friends (look into `fonttext.ltx`)

Also

- `\newenvironment \newtheorem`
- `\newcounter`

that indirectly define control sequences. All of these are either primitives or are defined in the LaTeX kernel.

Packages may introduce new ways to define control sequences. One case is `amsmath` (actually `amsopn`) that provides `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Why this wealth? Because one wants to avoid unnecessary code duplication. If you look into `t1enc.def` you will find several instances of `\DeclareTextAccent`, `\DeclareTextCommand` and `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand`. Of course they could be substituted with the lower level code at each call, but…

```
% latex.ltx, line 7345:
\def\DeclareTextCompositeCommand#1#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\reserved@a\csname#2\string#1\endcsname
  \ifx\reserved@a\relax
   \DeclareTextCommand#1{#2}{%
     \@latex@error{\string#1 undeclared in encoding #2}\@eha}%
   \@latex@info{Composite with undeclared \string#1 in encoding #2}%
   \expandafter\let\expandafter\reserved@a\csname#2\string#1\endcsname
  \fi
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx
  \expandafter\@car\reserved@a\relax\relax\@nil \@text@composite \else
      \edef\reserved@b##1{%
         \def\expandafter\noexpand
            \csname#2\string#1\endcsname####1{%
            \noexpand\@text@composite
               \expandafter\noexpand\csname#2\string#1\endcsname
               ####1\noexpand\@empty\noexpand\@text@composite
               {##1}}}%
      \expandafter\reserved@b\expandafter{\reserved@a{##1}}%
   \fi
   \expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\string\csname
      #2\endcsname\string#1-\string#3\@empty\endcsname{#4}%
  }
```

There are twelve instances of `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand` just in `t1enc.def` and so many others in the `.def` files for output encodings. Would you replace each of them with that preposterous piece of code? And I could have mentioned `\DeclareMathSymbol` that has an even longer definition and is used hundreds of times for assigning a meaning to the math symbol commands.

Of course not! And `\DeclareMathOperator` is in the same vein: in order to correctly define a command to stand for an operator there are several things to do and so `amsmath` provides an abstraction that frees the user from knowing the inner details that are irrelevant to them. You don't study how a microwave oven works in order to get one: you go to the shop and buy it.

Similarly, `\pgfmathsetmacro` is an abstraction that allows the user to employ the command to define a control sequence that will have the documented properties. The details of the implementation are known to the maintainers of PGF, just like the design of a microwave oven is known to the manufacturer.